What stain would match my paneling?
I'm moving out of a rental and a room where I had a whiteboard mounted to the wall had faux wood paneling. My landlord advised me to use wood filler/putty to patch the holes, however I'd like to take an extra step and make sure that the filled holes at least look the same color as the wall. Problem is, I have no idea what kind of wood this paneling is supposed to be simulating. Can anyone tell me what it might be so I have a place to start when looking for stains?


It's not going to match anyway unless you break out the tiny brushes and artist paint to replicate the grain pattern and black groove, and the landlord only asked for wood filler/putty. The ony way to find a "match" to the extent that isn't that would be to make up samples of your wood filler and apply stains to them, then compare them to the wall. At which point the tiny artist brushes begin to look like less work.

We can't look at a picture on the internet and tell you what stain to buy.  You will need to go the the home supply store and look at their samples and pic something that you believe will match. Also but a color lighter and darker.  Then you will need to be creative to get something that satisfies your desires.

@Ecnerwal I'm not looking to make it look like the holes were never there, I just want there not to be glaringly obvious natural-colored spots on the wall at a glance.

@RMDMan I was hoping that someone would be able to look at that paneling and clock what sort of wood it's supposed to be like so I have a place to start. The only wood I recognize immediately is pine and this ain't it.

Coloring is tough to match in the best situations.  Over the net is nothing but a guess.  This is absolutely a hands on and trial and error task.

Frame challenge: Hang a small piece of art over the holes?

I was hoping that someone would be able to look at that paneling ... nobody here can look at that paneling, we can only look at a picture, and that picture looks different on every device that is used to view the picture ... for example, on my tablet, the panel looks gray with blue lines

It's faux-oak, but specifically faux-oak with some sort of "pale" (perhaps "blonde" "pickled" or "bleached") faux-finish.

Your best bet is to take your filler, spread out some dabs on a piece of scrap wood, and let it dry.  Then get your best guess stain color and apply it to one of the dabs.  If it's too light, try another coat.  If too dark, try a lighter stain (or maybe dilute it with an appropriate thinner).
When it comes time to actually apply the filler to the wall, if you're really going for accuracy, you'll drag a small pointy tool across the surface to match the grain of the paneling.
That one right at the "joint" is really gonna test you, though!
